# Ash and Doleans-Dade Probability and Measure Theory Section 1.2 Question 2

Tags: measure-theory

Ok so in section 1.2 of chapter 1, the authors pose the following challenge:

Let $\mu$ be the counting measure on $\Omega$, where $\Omega$ is an infinite set. Show that there is a sequence of sets $A_{n} \downarrow \emptyset$ with $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mu(A_{n})\neq0$.

For some reason this problem is giving me a hard time. First of all, I'm assuming that since the authors distinguish between countably infinite and infinite in the previous question, that infinite implies that $\Omega$ is uncountably infinite. For that reason, I am taking my space $\Omega$ to be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. That being said, so far I have:

First we have a tuple $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mu)$, where $\mu$ is the counting measure. Now, let $A_{n} \subset \mathcal{F}$ be given by
$$
A_{n}=\left(a-\frac{1}{n},a \right) \cup \left(a,a+\frac{1}{n}\right)
$$
and then we have that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} A_{n}=\bigcap^{\infty}_{n=1} \left( \left(a-\frac{1}{n},a \right) \cup \left(a,a+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)=\emptyset
$$
so I've constructed a sequence of sets whose limit is the null set. Now the part I'm struggling on is finding a sequence of sets whose limit is the null set and has counting measure $\mu >0$. My idea was to have another set $B$ be defined by
$$
B=(a-1,a+1)
$$
and then define a sequence of disjoint sets $B_{n} \subset B$ by partitioning $B$ dyadically so that
$$
B_{n}=(2^{-(n-1)}-a,2^{-n}-a) \, \cup \, (2^{-n}+a,2^{-(n-1)}+a)
$$
then I want something like
$$
\lim_{N \to \infty}\left(\bigcup^{N}_{n=1} B_{n}\right)^{c}=\{a\}
$$
since the sequence $B_{n}$ will never include $\{a\}$ itself but $\{a\}$ IS an element of $B$ and by that same reasoning
$$
\bigcap^{\infty}_{n=1} B_{n} = \emptyset
$$
then we have that
$$
\mu\left(\left(\bigcup^{\infty}_{n=1} B_{n} \right)^{c}\right)=1
$$
since $\mu$ is the counting measure and the cardinality of $\{a\}$ is 1.

I just want to know if I am on the right track here or am I missing something. I just started learning measure theory this week so I apologize if I made some trivial error here.

Comment: I'd suggest giving the problem a try in the case $\Omega=\mathbb{N}$. I suspect that the authors only said infinite because it doesn't matter whether $\Omega$ is countable or not.

Comment: Whoops I guess I had a brain fart on the first part but I think my sets $B_{n}$ do not have this error, right?

Comment: I edited it with correction

Answer (score 1):

Let $A_n=\{a_n\}$ where $a_n$ is any infinite sequence in $\Omega$ such that $a_i\neq a_j$ for $i\neq j$. Then $\lim_n A_n=\{\phi\}$ but $\mu(A_n)=1$ for all $n$.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit further..I'm just having a hard time seeing this

Comment: Well as an example take $\Omega$ to be the positive integers and let $a_n=n$.

Comment: Oh duh, took me a second but now I see it. Thanks!